# Java Restlet - How do I dynamically attach resources to the router?

Tags: java, resources, restlet, mashup

Here's the basics of what I'm trying to do. I'm working on a project where I'm creating a mashup page from various web APIs. The mashup page contains country information.

I have a  BLL layer where I create the mashup page (html page with country input using Chunk Library). This is the method used to set up the template

```
public String GetTemplate(Country country) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("BLL/themes/page.html");
    Theme theme = new Theme("src/BLL", "themes");

    Chunk html = theme.makeChunk("page", "html");

    html.set("countryName", country.getName());
    html.set("countryCode", country.getCode());
    html.set("countryContinent", country.getContinent());
    html.set("countryCapital", country.getCapital());
    html.set("countryAreaInSqKm", country.getAreaInSqKm());
    html.set("countryPopulation", country.getPopulation());
    html.set("countryCurrencyCode", country.getCurrencyCode());
    html.set("countryExchangeRate", country.getExchangeRate());
    html.set("countryFlagUrl", country.getFlagUrl());
    html.set("countryDescription", country.getDescription());
    html.set("countryMap", country.getMapLocation());

    return html.toString();
}
```

Eventually I'll be using a database for all available countries.

So what I want to do on the Restlet server is iterate through all countries, like so, or in a similar manner?

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/countries/", Countries.class);
    for (Country country : cm.GetAllCountries()) {
         router.attach("/countries/" + country.getName(), new CountryTemplate(country)); 
         // Obviously this doesn't work, and it doesn't work with getClass() either.
    }

    return router;
}
```

As such I'm trying to get my resource to return the html in the get method (from the TemplateManager):

```
public class CountryTemplate extends ServerResource {
    CountryManager cm = null;
    TemplateManager tm = null;
    Country country = null;

    public CountryTemplate(Country _country) throws Exception {
        cm = new CountryManager();
        tm = new TemplateManager();
        country = _country;
    }

    @Get("html")
    public String getTemplate() throws IOException, RemoteException, UnsupportedCurrencyException {
        return tm.GetTemplate(country);
    }
}
```

Is there indeed a way to do it like this, or am I approaching this all wrong?

**If anyone else should find themselves here, Tim's code worked exactly as required. The posted code was altered to his version.**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could you give a finger point? :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about my answer.  We could move to a chat if you wish.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed, thank you! I think I marked it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to hard-code dynamic dynamic behaviors of your REST resources, you should be using a query parameter.

First, you can create a new REST resource `/countries/html/` and bind it to the class `CountryResource`.  This resource will accept a query parameter `countryID` corresponding to the country whose HTML you want to access:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/countries/", Countries.class);
    router.attach("/countries/html/", CountryResource.class); 

    return router;
}
```

In your definition for `CountryResource`, you can access the query parameter `countryID` to get the appropriate HTML content:

```
public class CountryResource extends ServerResource {
    CountryManager cm;
    TemplateManager tm;

    public CountryTemplate() throws Exception {
        // Note: I usually do NOT define a constructor using Restlets,
        // but you should be OK doing this
        cm = new CountryManager();
        tm = new TemplateManager();
    }

    @Get("html")
    public String getTemplate() throws IOException, RemoteException, UnsupportedCurrencyException {
        String countryID = getQueryValue("countryID");
        Country country = tm.getCountry(countryID);

        return tm.GetTemplate(country);
    }
}
```

I assume that the `CountryManager` has a method `getCountry()` which can return a `Country` object based on an input String.  If such a method does not currently exist, then you will need to find a way to map incoming query parameters to actual `Country` objects in your code.

Comment: So, I would access a country like so:  http://localhost:8182/countries/html?countryID=swe/  <--- For sweden for example if we say that is the ID

Comment: Ahhh, I stand corrected, the correct way to access it is: http://localhost:8182/countries/html/?countryID=dk